# How to use for loop to remove items from array of array without using js methods?

Tags: javascript

I'm using for loop to remove only 3 from array of array?

I have tried few conditional statements but it's not working for me.

```js
let myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 4, 3],
  [3, 6, 7],
  [3, 8, 9]
];
let newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] !== 3) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i]);
    console.log(newArray);
  }
}
```

I am expect the output 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9, but actual output is with 3.

Comment: `[...] !=3` is `true` - always, you want to iterate over  subarray also

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. is it a nested array?

Comment: I think you made a mistake, may `myArray` would be smth like that?

`let myArray = [
  1, 2, 3,
  5, 4, 3,
  3, 6, 7,
  3, 8, 9
];` - without nested arrays

Comment: you may want to add to your question that you want only a single for loop - good luck

Answer (score 2):

```js
let myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 4, 3],
  [3, 6, 7],
  [3, 8, 9]
];
let newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
for(let j=0; j< myArray[i].length; j++) {
  if (myArray[i][j] != 3) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i][j]);
  }
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Yea, i saw your answer after posting mine

Comment: push is a js method

Comment: @Jaromanda X I think he meant not to use any js library, or any array methods like .flat etc. Atleast thats what my understanding was. :-)

Comment: why is filter or map excluded but not push?

Comment: @Iffy - you can't do that because you have 2 dimensional array and oddly specific exclusions

Answer (score 1):

`myArray[i]` is an array, you have to loop through the items of `myArray[i]` as well.

```js
let myArray = [ [1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3], [3, 6, 7], [3, 8, 9]];
let newArray = [];
for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++) {
    if (myArray[i][j] != 3) {
      newArray.push(myArray[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: push is a js method

Comment: @JaromandaX, I think OP meant to say `map()`,`filter()`, `reduce()....`

Comment: but OP didn't say that - why should they be excluded?

Comment: I would like to solve error with 1 for loop not twice.

Comment: @Iffy you can't do that with a two dimensional array and "no js methods" - you may want to add this extra condition to the question

Comment: @Mamun - I know - I'm highlighting the fact that the question is a pointless exercise in futility

Answer (score 1):

You have a two dimentional array but you are treating it like is one dimentional array.

Try the following:

```
let myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 4, 3],
  [3, 6, 7],
  [3, 8, 9]
];
let newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push([]);
  for (let j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
     if (myArray[i][j] != 3) {
       newArray[i].push(myArray[i][j]);           
     }
   }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: push is a js method

Comment: I would like to solve error with 1 for loop not twice.

Comment: @Iffy you can't do that with a two dimensional array and "no js methods"

Comment: @Iffy You can solve it with one look using the formula `i*myArray.length + j` in a reversed way but this is not a canonical array and you could have more items in `myArray[0]` from `myArray[1]`. Why you need one loop? Two loops are the same fast as one loop if you are counting the same length.

Comment: @JaromandaX `length` is a JS method too! Both `push` and `length` are how we use arrays in JS. I suppose the OP didn't need any functional arrays such as `map`, `flat` etc

Comment: technically, length is a property :p @MenelaosVergis - and why is push "allowed" and other perfectly usable methods not - the question has arbitrary limitations (like single loop, making it impossible)

Answer (score 1):

This is a single loop approach by using a dynamic check of the length, depending on the actual loop purpose.

You could assign all values and take for the nested array a new index `k` to assign to the right index. This index is only incremented on a valid value.

```js
var myArray = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3], [3, 6, 7], [3, 8, 9]],
    newArray = [],
    i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < (myArray[j] || myArray).length; i++) {
    if (j === undefined) {
        j = i;
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        newArray[j] = [];
    }
    if (myArray[j][i] !== 3) {
        newArray[j][k++] = myArray[j][i];
    }
    if (i + 1 >= myArray[j].length) {
         i = j;
         j = undefined;
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: excellent, but a new twist - only one loop allowed (and if someone comes up with an answer for that, I'm sure OP will change the parameters again)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your flow.
Here is what your code should look like:

```js
var newArray = [];
var temp = [];
var myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 4, 3],
  [3, 6, 7],
  [3, 8, 9]
];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  temp = [];
  for( var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
    if (myArray[i][j] != 3) {
      temp[j]= myArray[i][j];
    }
  }
  newArray[i] = temp;
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: push is a js method :

Comment: OP wants a single for loop now (you'll never win with this one :p )

Comment: look at the comments in all the answers that were posted before yours :p